# Prevent Windows from signing me into Windows Live automatically

Tags: email, hotmail

I am currently using Windows Live mail as an email client. When I sign out and open the client again, it prompts for credentials.  However, as soon as I restart my computer, it does not prompt me for credentials when I open up my emails again, I get signed in automatically.

How can I prevent Windows from signing me into Windows Live Mail automatically, even after a clean boot or restart?

Comment: Which web browser are you using? What do you mean by a "clean boot"?

Answer (score 0):

You should configure it from within the program after signing in, per the image below, unchecking "Allow automatic sign in when connected to the Internet":

[image: Windows Live Options dialog]